# Vuex getter authenticated returns false in route guard. I assume it evaluates to false because at the time of calling autoLogin hasn't executed yet

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

So I have a `/login` route that renders the login view and I'm trying to make it so that if the user is already logged in, he gets redirected to another route. The problem is that when I type the url `www.example.com/login`, `authenticated` evaluates to false for some reason. This is how my code works:

Login Url:

```
{
    path: '/login',
    name: 'login',
    component: Login,
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
        if (store.getters.authenticated) {
            next({ name: "adminOrders" })
        } else {
            next()
        }
    }
},
```

Vuex authentication store:

```
import router from '../router'
import axios from 'axios'

const authentication = {
    state: {
        user: null
    },
    mutations: {
        setUser(state, user){
            state.user = user
            localStorage.setItem('userId', user.id);
            localStorage.setItem('username', user.username);
            localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
        }
    },
    actions: {
        autoLogin({commit, dispatch}){
            const userId = localStorage.getItem('userId')
            const username = localStorage.getItem('username')
            const token = localStorage.getItem('token')

            if (!token) {
                return
            }

            let user = {
                id: userId,
                username: username,
                token: token
            }

            commit('setUser', user)

            axios.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
                config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + token

                return config
            });
        },
    },
    getters: {
        authenticated: state => {
            return state.user ? true : false
        }
    }
}

export default authentication
```

And I call the autoLogin on App.vue mounted like this:

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
        <router-view/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        mounted(){
            this.$store.dispatch('autoLogin');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`beforeEnter` is called before `App` is mounted, because router gets instantiated as soon as `App` is created.

Since you call `autoLogin` action from App's `mounted()` it's actually run after the router reads the getter from the store.

However, you could call an `async` action from `beforeEnter`, which would return whether or not there is a token in localStorage.

At a minimum, here's what would work:

```
// routes:
  beforeEnter: async (to, from, next) => {
    const hasToken = await store.dispatch('hasToken');
    next(hasToken ? { name: 'adminOrders' } : undefined);
  }

// store:
  actions: {
    hasToken() {
      return !!localStorage.getItem('token')
    }
    // ...
  }
```

Make sure you wipe the `token` out from `localStorage` when you get a [`401` error](https://httpstatuses.com/401)  in your axios interceptors (basically means "token expired"). If you do not clear the `token` from `localStorage` before trying to go to `/login` (which is what usually happens on `401`), the `beforeEnter` will redirect to `adminOrders`, `adminOrders` will attempt to load data, data calls will return `401` as `token` is expired and you end up in a loop.
Alternatively, you could just get a new `token` on `401`'s and update `localStorage`.